# Unable to access MTP mounted device from the terminal?

Tags: linux, mount, fedora-36

I've plugged my phone onto my computer and enabled "file sharing" from Android.

I can easily access the files (photo, folders, downloads, etc) from Nautilus (Gnome on Fedora 36) but somehow, there is absolutely no folders under `/run/user/{uid}/gvfs/`

I went down the rabbit hole, and tried to manually mount the device using `gio mount "mtp://device_name"` and even via the USB code. When doing that I have the error "The device does not implement mounting" (sorry for the loose translation, it's in French).

Searching on Internet, I found that running the DBus command solve this, so I ran `dbus-run-session bash` and retried the command, which then seemed to work:

```
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' requested by ':1.0' (uid=0 pid=59808 comm="gio mount mtp://OnePlus_OnePlus_992770bb/" label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.0' (uid=0 pid=59808 comm="gio mount mtp://OnePlus_OnePlus_992770bb/" label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.UDisks2VolumeMonitor'
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.0' (uid=0 pid=59808 comm="gio mount mtp://OnePlus_OnePlus_992770bb/" label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.MTPVolumeMonitor'
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.0' (uid=0 pid=59808 comm="gio mount mtp://OnePlus_OnePlus_992770bb/" label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Activating service name='org.gnome.OnlineAccounts' requested by ':1.4' (uid=0 pid=59830 comm="/usr/libexec/gvfs-goa-volume-monitor" label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
goa-daemon-Message: 09:57:06.148: goa-daemon version 3.44.0 starting
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Activating service name='org.gnome.Identity' requested by ':1.5' (uid=0 pid=59834 comm="/usr/libexec/goa-daemon" label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.OnlineAccounts'
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GoaVolumeMonitor'
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Identity'
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.0' (uid=0 pid=59808 comm="gio mount mtp://OnePlus_OnePlus_992770bb/" label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")

(process:59843): libgoaidentity-WARNING **: 09:57:06.164: GoaKerberosIdentityManager: Using polling for change notification for credential cache type 'KCM'
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.GPhoto2VolumeMonitor'
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Activating service name='org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor' requested by ':1.0' (uid=0 pid=59808 comm="gio mount mtp://OnePlus_OnePlus_992770bb/" label="unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023")
dbus-daemon[59784]: [session uid=0 pid=59784] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.AfcVolumeMonitor'
Device 0 (VID=2a70 and PID=f003) is a OnePlus OnePlus 2 A2005.
Android device detected, assigning default bug flags
```

But the gvfs is still empty!

As a reminder, using Nautilus works perfectly well, but I want to access via terminal.

What is happening ?

Thanks!